# tomcat webservice publishing

Tags: tomcat, web-services

if i know that a tomcat is publishing a webservice but i don't know its url.
How can i discover what webservice this tomcat is publishing?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to what you are asking is [UDDI](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javawebserv/chapter/ch06.html) although the question is pretty vague.